# C# how to get the row header from mysql database table

Tags: c#, mysql

Good day sir and ma'am. I'm planning to get all row header like "column_id and first_name, last_name and so on" and populate my listbox with row header from mysql database table. Please enlighten me how to do this. I am not sure what to use MySqlDataAdapter or MySqlDataReader. I'm beginner and willing to learn.

```
        using (MySqlConnection conns2 = new MySqlConnection(connString)) 
        {
            conns2.Open();
            MySqlCommand comm2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table1", 
            conns2);
            MySqlDataAdapter add2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(comm2);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            add2.Fill(dt2);
            foreach(DataColumn column in dt2.Columns)
            {
                columnlistbox.Items.Add(dt2.Columns); 
                //it shows "collection" and exactly the number of row header 
                //but it doesn't show like "First name, client_id and last 
                //name"
            }
            conns2.Close();
        }
```

Comment: check if is work in mysql https://stackoverflow.com/a/7159610/1271037

Comment: you could execute `select {whatever} from {whereever} where 1 = 0`...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24840500/1271037 And what if he does not know any table name? Can not write `select 123`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `MySqlDataAdapter` is the appropriate choice based on the sample code you provided because you are populating a DataTable and in ADO.NET DataAdapters are traditionally used to populate DataTables. A DataAdapter populates or "fills" your DataTable object.

You could also use a DataReader to populate your DataTable:

```
var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(dataReader);
```

DataAdapters and DataReaders are a core design concept of ADO.NET, whether using Sql Server or MySQL database. A DataReader is a forward only, light and faster Database query helper. A DataAdapter is a bit heavier than a DataReader and also does more than a DataReader can do, it is possible that a DataAdapter uses a DataReader behind the scenes.

Here is how you would use the data from your MySQL database, you need to use a DataGrid, not a ListBox

```
     using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString)) 
    {
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table1", 
        conn);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        //display your dataset in a ASP.NET Web Forms DataGrid
        dataGrid.DataSource = dt;
        dataGrid.DataBind();

        //conn.Close();// you do not need this, your using statements call Dispose and Dispose will release the connection back to the connection pool
    }
```

Comment: Sir Brian this is actually good and somehow what I'm looking for but there's only one question I got for this and hoping that you enlighten me about this. Sir is there a way not to use DataTextField and DataValueField? because I'm planning to add 20 more row headers that means these 20 row headers like Client_ID will be showing up on listbox. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes you should use an ASP.NET Web Forms DataGrid not a ListBox

Comment: A DataGrid will AutoGenerate the columns and rows out of the box, you can also completely customize the DataGrid, I updated my answer to demonstrate binding to DataGrid

Answer (score 1):

### for get columns names from a DataTable

If you need data from the db, and you load it into a DataTable (using DbDataAdapter or DbDataReader), you can know the column names from the DataTable.Columns collection property:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt2.Columns)
    columnlistbox.Items.Add(col.ColumnName);
```

### get only schema from MySql db (tables, columns ect)

but if you not need any data from the DB, but only its structure, you can use the DbDataReader. for load this data by the reader, a query must be "simulated" to the database:

```
using (MySqlConnection conns2 = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    conns2.Open();
    MySqlCommand comm2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table1", conns2);

    using (var reader = MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
    {
        reader.Read();
        var dtSchema = reader.GetSchemaTable();

        foreach (DataRow row in tableSchema.Rows)
            columnlistbox.Items.Add(row["ColumnName"]);

    }
}
```

form https://stackoverflow.com/a/7159610/1271037:

Comment: This is actually good but why there is 1 = 2? and why didn't you include the adding of column name to columnlistbox sir?

Comment: This is to ensure that there will be no unnecessary data loading. This is of course if there is no need for data but only in their structure. and i'm edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pointers from this code.  In summary `GetName` is what you are looking for.

```
using (Common.DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table1";
    dynamic dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int index = 0;
    List<string> columns = new List<string>();

    for (index = 0; index <= dr.FieldCount - 1; index++) {

        columns.Add(dr.GetName(index));
    }

}
```

Comment: @BrianOgden would you care to elaborate.  As I understood, the question was how to retrieve column header names.

Comment: I see more now what you are trying to answer, aka I see your point and your answer helps, I was incorrect in saying your answer is not a good answer